# Using BinaryReader with TcpListener, not getting data when I try BinaryReader.ReadString(Stream)

Tags: c#, binaryreader

```
    public static void ClientListener(object obj)                       
    {

        TcpClient client = (TcpClient)obj;                              
        NetworkStream netStream = client.GetStream();
        var br = new BinaryReader(netStream);
        var rec = new Record();
        string s = br.ReadString();
        Console.WriteLine(s);
        netStream.Close();                                                 
        client.Close(); 
    }
```

I know that I'm receiving data, and if I transpose the data into an array and convert it to string, I can read some of the data. The problem is, this data is coming from a struct in another language (delphi), and I have no control over it, nor do I know exactly what it looks like.
I know the first two sets of data are strings, and they have a max of 255 bytes each.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, I'm new to C#.

Comment: it can be that strings doesn't ended with appropriate end string symbols. In this case use byte reading (ReadBytes()) is a best decision.      Not connected with your issue, but it's better to use binary reader inside using scope: using(BinaryReader br=new BinaryReader(netStream)) {..}

Comment: Thank you for the reply! 
So, I'm getting about 1324 bytes of data, containing a 11 different values, some strings, some ints.  

Could you give me some clues on how to us ReadBytes() in this case to handle this?

Comment: That's a good question. You should analyze you byte array. I assume there should be the special symbol that separates values from each other. Basically I would've convert whole byte array to string to find out where the special symbols is placed and then use bytereader to find out how those symbols are coded in bytes. I hope it helps.

Comment: That's what I've been trying to avoid doing. Doesn't seem like there are special symbols. 

Thanks for your help though. You put me back on the right track (I think!)